# how return value to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code here that successfully alerts "Success" from the echo of submit.php.

```
var result = $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "ajax/submit.php",
             datatype: "html",
             data: "&data="+$_employmentBackground,
             async: false
            }).responseText;

alert(result);
```

but when I put if statement around, it is not working anymore..

```
if(result == "Success")
{
   alert(result);
}
```

Do you have any idea why is it not working?

Comment: check `typeof result`

Comment: type of result? what should it be?

Comment: Why `async:false`? Just do the logic inside the callback...

Comment: I suppose you're sending some trailing spaces to the response, this would explain why the condition is false

Comment: `alert(typeof result)` it should be string

Comment: First of all read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You can use FireBug and put a breakpoint on if, then check what kind of object `result` is.

Comment: Fabrizio may be right, try it like this: `if(result.trim() == "Success")`

Comment: Refer to the Ajax 101 guide at http://fixingthesejquery.com/images/ajax101.png and the marvellous http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide33

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` then in PHP `echo json_encode('Success')`

Comment: THANKS FOR ALL THE COMMENT @FabrizioCalderan is right, its because of the spaces.. :)

Comment: @QKWS so answer to your own question and mark it as accepted (I'm not looking for easy rep)